# Android custom list view with custom adapter not clear

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I want a custom list view with a custom array adapter.I found this blog post but customadapter.java is unclear. I can do the about with default simple_list_1.

Here is the blog post http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/

How is constructor getting called.How is static class called.Totally,I'm not able to under stand the flow of the program.

Thank you.

Comment: are u looking for the custom list view tutorials which explain you in the better way

Answer (score 0):

getview() method will be called automatocally for every list you will add.

Take a look [here](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-arrayadapter-and-listview-in-android-applications) for more explanation on array adapter.
Hope it will help.